# GreenSock - after animation links are not clickable in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, animation, 3d, gsap

Have very strange behaviour that is not working only in Google Chrome but works in Firefox. 
I have a cube with only side pages (without top and bottom) - so I have 4 pages and I rotate them for 90 degrees left and right.

Here is the the LIVE example (everything is in the page - JS libraries are taken from CDN, CSS is inline, no images):
http://www.cloomo.com/problem

How to simulate the error:

- Start Google Chrome and go to http://www.cloomo.com/problem
- Go to the Page 3 (it has green background) and you will see that links
  "Back 2" and "Page 4" are not working and their text can not even
  beselected with a mouse.
- You can come to Page 3 by clicking on "Page 2" > "Page 3" or "Left" > "Left"

Can you help me to make these links clickable?

Is there an error in CSS styles or in GreeSock library? I can not find it, because nothing is reported.

Another question:

Is it possible to make it more smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the greensock animation, it's in cube itself.

When you set

```
.cube {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
```

and then rotate the cube 180 deg, the cube itself is hidden.

On top of that, the third face is rotated 180 deg, and that makes it be front face and be visible... but the anchors in it won't be clickables (Some how, Chrome is loosing the ability to handle mouse events when an the parent is not visible),

As you say, this is a Chromw specific problem, Firefox handles it ok. (And IE doesn't handle backface visibility at all)

But, backface-visibility hidden isn't needed on the cube in your design, so drop it and everything will be ok.